# Transition is not working properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've made a custom cursor for my next website. In Chrome it works as it should but in Safari it's laggy...

I've tried several things like using the webkit stuff but it still doesn't work.

here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lardtom/pen/XWEdYVo)

html

```
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

css

```
body{
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.cursor{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;

    transition-duration:0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.3s;
    -ms-transition-duration:0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.3s;

    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.33,.81,.66,.95);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.33,.81,.66,.95);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.33,.81,.66,.95);
    background-color: #fff;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

js

```
let cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor);

function moveCursor(e) {
    let x = e.clientX;
    let y = e.clientY;

    cursor.style.transform = `translate(calc(${x}px - 50%), calc(${y}px - 50%))`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my particular case was pretty interesting.

Instead of using css transitions I used a lerp function in javascript:

```js
var mouseX = window.innerWidth / 2,
  mouseY = window.innerHeight / 2;
var $ = jQuery


var circle = {
  el: $('.cursor'),
  x: window.innerWidth / 2,
  y: window.innerHeight / 2,
  w: 25,
  h: 25,
  update: function() {
    l = this.x - this.w / 2;
    t = this.y - this.h / 2;
    this.el.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + l + 'px, ' + t + 'px, 0)'
    });
  }
}

$(window).mousemove(function(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
})

setInterval(move, 1000 / 60)

function move() {
  circle.x = lerp(circle.x, mouseX, 0.1);
  circle.y = lerp(circle.y, mouseY, 0.1);
  circle.update()
}

function lerp(start, end, amt) {
  return (1 - amt) * start + amt * end
}
```

```css
.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

r

Answer (score 0):

I've had nothing but trouble with dynamic `transform` values in safari.  It seems they calculate positions in the window space a little different than other browsers.  No source on that one, just my own trials and tribulations.

I would suggest you change your approach, and use `top` and `left` values.

I tested this in safari and it's miles more responsive.

```js
let cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor);

function moveCursor(e) {
  let x = e.clientX;
  let y = e.clientY;

  cursor.style.top = `${y}px`
  cursor.style.left = `${x}px`
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.33, .81, .66, .95);
  background-color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

I kept the `translate(-50%, -50%)` as a permanent value on the cursor, and only updated `top` and `left` with javascript.

As a side note, the vendor prefixes are not really necessary for those properties.  No need to add them. https://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: for some reason it is laggy on chrome too when I use the top, left method.

Answer (score 0):

The translate calc in you js is forcing the cursor to the center.

The transition delay is too long preventing it for following the cursor.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/diomedefan/pen/RwMaYWe

```js
let cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', moveCursor);

function moveCursor(e) {
    let x = e.clientX;
    let y = e.clientY;

    cursor.style.transform = `translate(calc(${x}px), calc(${y}px))`
}
```

```css
body{
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.cursor{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;

    transition-duration:0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.2s;
    -ms-transition-duration:0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration:0.2s;

    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.33,.81,.66,.95);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.33,.81,.66,.95);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.33,.81,.66,.95);
    background-color: #fff;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    border-radius: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>
```